# Problemas en funcion update de Laravel

Tags: laravel, update

estoy intentando actualizar un campo que envio desde mi vista en la funcion update utilizando un input de tipo radio para seleccionar la opcion, el dato que envio para que busque donde se hara la actualizacion es CodSoli aclaro que por cuestiones de como debe trabajar el sistema no es autoincrementable, el problema es que me marca error a la hora de hacerlo y quisiera una guia de las cosas que debo corregir para lograrlo.

el formulario de la vista de la que envio los datos:

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{ route('sistema.update',$solicitante->CodSoli) }}"  role="form">
       {{ csrf_field() }}
       <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Nombre">Nombre</label>
          <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control input-sm"  value="{{$solicitante->NomSoli}}" readonly>
           <label for="Apellido">Apellido</label>
          <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control input-sm"  value="{{$solicitante->ApeSoli}}" readonly> 
          <label for="EstatusCaso">Estatus del Caso</label>
          <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="Seguimiento" name="EstatusCaso" id="estatus" checked>Seguimiento</label>
          <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="Cerrado" name="EstatusCaso" id="estatus">Cerrado</label>                  
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
         <input type="submit"  value="Actualizar" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
         <a href="{{ route('sistema.index') }}" class="btn btn-info btn-block" >Atrás</a>
        </div>
```

El codigo de la funcion update:

```
    public function update(Request $request, $cod)
    {
        $datos=Caso::select('EstatusCaso')->where('CodSoli', $cod);
        $this->validate($request,[ 'EstatusCaso'=>'required']);

        $datos->update($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('sistema.index')->with('success','Registro actualizado satisfactoriamente');
    }
```

Comment: ¿Que error es el que obtienes?

Comment: este: 
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: no existe la columna «_token» en la relación «Casos» LINE 1: update "Casos" set "_token" = $1, "_method" = $2, "nombre" =... ^ (SQL: update "Casos" set "_token" = FRnPjumsEkJWdTBAe098MN6fPbhw0fAKDgOBEnve, "_method" = PATCH, "nombre" = medina, "EstatusCaso" = Seguimiento, "updated_at" = 2019-12-13 15:17:59 where "CodSoli" = 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la función update remueve el campo `_token`

```
$datos->update($request->except('_token'));
```